# How to split CSV line according to specific pattern

Tags: regex, string, csv, split

In a .csv file I have lines like the following :

```
10,"nikhil,khandare","sachin","rahul",viru
```

I want to split line using comma (,).  However I don't want to split words between double quotes (" ").  If I split using comma I will get array with the following items:

```
10  
nikhil  
khandare  
sachin  
rahul  
viru
```

But I don't want the items between double-quotes to be split by comma. My desired result is:

```
10
nikhil,khandare
sachin
rahul
viru
```

Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Please add the code you already made, so we can help you fixing it.

Comment: its not possible to do so using simple perl code. i use TEST::CSV module to do so

Comment: What language do you want to use? Probably the best thing to do is to use an already existing CSV parsing library.

Answer (score 2):

The character used for separating fields should not be present in the fields themselves. If possible, replace `,` with `;` for separating fields in the csv file, it'll make your life easier. But if you're stuck with using `,` as separator, you can split each line using this regular expression:

```
/((?:[^,"]|"[^"]*")+)/
```

For example, in Python:

```
import re
s = '10,"nikhil,khandare","sachin","rahul",viru'
re.split(r'((?:[^,"]|"[^"]*")+)', s)[1::2]
=> ['10', '"nikhil,khandare"', '"sachin"', '"rahul"', 'viru']
```

Now to get the *exact* result shown in the question, we only need to remove those extra `"` characters:

```
[e.strip('" ') for e in re.split(r'((?:[^,"]|"[^"]*")+)', s)[1::2]]
=> ['10', 'nikhil,khandare', 'sachin', 'rahul', 'viru']
```

Comment: Thank you :) I believe this is the right tool for the job in this case

Answer (score 1):

If you really have such a simple structure always, you can use splitting with "," (yes, with quotes) after discarding first number and comma

If no, you can use a very simple form of [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) parsing your input from left to right. You will have two states: insides quotes and outside. Regular expressions is a also a good (and simpler) way if you already know them (as they are basically an equivalent of state machine, just in another form)

Comment: Using a state machine for parsing a string. That's how most regular expression engines work, why not recommend using a regular expression instead?

Comment: See my answer, I wrote a regular expression that will correctly parse OP's input